# why is kubernetes using its own base64 format?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-secrets

When I use base64 inside Ubuntu to encode admin, I get: YWRtaW4K. But when I see secret in kubernetes I get YWRtaW4=.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gBC8H.png)

Comment: The second one is with padding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the trailing newline character from the input; you can use the `-n` switch to trim the trailing new line from the `echo` command and get the same behavior as seen with the Kubernetes secrets.

```
echo -n  "admin" |base64
YWRtaW4=


echo -n "YWRtaW4=" |base64 -d
admin
```